# Assign numbers to each letter so that r calculates the sum of the letters in a word

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a tool in R that will calculate the atomic composition (i.e. number of carbon, hydrogen, nitrogen and oxygen atoms) of a peptide chain that is input in single letter amino acid code. For example, the peptide KGHLY consists of the amino acids lysine (K), glycine (G), histidine (H), leucine (L) and tyrosine (Y). Lysine is made of 6 carbon, 13 hydrogen, 1 nitrogen and 2 oxygen. Glycine is made of 2 carbon, 5 hydrogen, 1 nitrogen and 2 oxygen. etc. etc.
I would like the r code to either read the peptide string (KGHLY) from a data frame or take input from the keyboard using readline()
I am new to R and new to programming. I am able to make objects for each amino acid, e.g. G <- c(2, 5, 1, 2) or build a data frame containing all 20 amino acids and their respective atomic compositions.
The bit that I am struggling with is that I don't know how to get R to index from a data frame in response to a string of letters. I have a feeling the solution is probably very simple but so far I have not been able to find a function that is suited to this task.

Comment: Split the string (use `strplit`) then use `match`. If you want code in an answer, you'll need to make a small, reproducible, illustrative example. [See tips on that here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061). People will be very happy if you use simulated data or use `dput()` to share data.

Comment: what would be helpful in this case is a sample of how your input is structured (maybe a vector of peptides and a "cost" matrix" - a matrix of amino acids with the quantity of each element); this is more or less what you describe in your question. `dput` this data in your question, and I think we could help you with some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two main components to take care of here: The selection of
a method for the storing of the basic data and the algorithm that
computes the result you desire.

For the computation, it might be preferable to have your data
stored in a matrix, due to the way R recycles the shorter vector
when multiplying two vectors.  This recycling also kicks in if you
want to multiply a matrix with a vector, since a matrix is a
vector with some additional attributes (that is to say, dimension
and dimension-names).  Consider the example below to see how it
works

```
test_matrix <- matrix(data = 1:12, nrow = 3)
test_vec <- c(3, 0, 1)

test_matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12

test_matrix * test_vec
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3   12   21   30
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    6    9   12
```

Based on this observation, it's possible to deduce that a solution
where each amino acid has one row in a matrix might be a good way
to store the *look up data*; when we have a *counting vector* with
specifying the desired amount of contribution from each row, it
will be sufficient to multiply our matrix with our *counting
vector*, and then sum the columns - the last part solved using
`colSums`.

```
colSums(test_matrix * test_vec)
[1]  6 18 30 42
```

It's in general a "pain" to store this kind of information in a
matrix, since it might be a "lot of work" to update the
information later on.  However, I guess it's not that often it's
required to add new amino acids, so that might not be an issue in
this case.

So let's create a matrix for the the five amino acids needed
for the peptide you mentioned in your example.  The numbers was
found on Wikipedia, and hopefully I didn't mess up when I copied
them.  Just follow suit to add all the other amino acids too.

```
amino_acids <- rbind(
    G = c(C = 2, H = 5,  N = 1, O = 2),
    L = c(C = 6, H = 13, N = 1, O = 2),
    H = c(C = 6, H = 9,  N = 3, O = 2),
    K = c(C = 6, H = 14, N = 2, O = 2),
    Y = c(C = 9, H = 11, N = 1, O = 3))

amino_acids
  C  H N O
G 2  5 1 2
L 6 13 1 2
H 6  9 3 2
K 6 14 2 2
Y 9 11 1 3
```

This matrix contains the information we want, but it might be
preferable to have them in lexicographic order - and it would be
nice to ensure that we haven't by mistake added the same row
twice.  The code below takes care of both of these issues.

```
amino_acids <-
    amino_acids[sort(unique(rownames(amino_acids))), ]

amino_acids                   
  C  H N O
G 2  5 1 2
H 6  9 3 2
K 6 14 2 2
L 6 13 1 2
Y 9 11 1 3
```

The next part is to figure out how to deal with the peptides.  This
will here be done by first using `strsplit` to split the string
into separate characters, and then use a `table`-solution upon the
result to get the vector that we want to multiply with the matrix.

```
peptide <- "KGHLY"

peptide_2 <- unlist(strsplit(x = peptide, split = ""))
peptide_2
[1] "K" "G" "H" "L" "Y"
```

Using `table` upon `peptide_2` gives us

```
table(peptide_2)
peptide_2
G H K L Y 
1 1 1 1 1
```

This can thus be used to define a vector to play the role of `test_vec` in the first example.  However, in general the resulting vector will contain fewer components than the rows of the matrix `amino_acids`; so a restriction must be performed first, in order to get the correct format we want for our computation.

Several options is available, and the simplest one might be to use the names from the table to subset the required rows from `amino_acids`, such that the computation can proceed without any further fuzz.

```
peptide_vec <- table(peptide_2)

colSums(amino_acids[names(peptide_vec), ] * as.vector(peptide_vec))
 C  H  N  O 
29 52  8 11
```

This outlines one possible solution for the core of your problem,
and this can be collected into a function that takes care of all
the steps for us.

```
peptide_function <- function(peptide, amino_acids) {
    peptide_vec <- table(
        unlist(strsplit(x = peptide, split = "")))
    ## Compute the result and return it to the work flow.
    colSums(
        amino_acids[names(peptide_vec), ] *
        as.vector(peptide_vec))
}
```

And finally a test to see that we get the same answer as before.

```
peptide_function(peptide = "GHKLY",
                 amino_acids = amino_acids)
 C  H  N  O 
29 52  8 11
```

What next?  Well that depends on how you have stored your
peptides, and what you would like to do with the result.  If for
example you have the peptides stored in a vector, and would like
to have the result stored in a matrix, then it might e.g. be
possible to use `vapply` as given below.

```
data_vector <- c("GHKLY", "GGLY", "HKLGL")

result <- t(vapply(
    X = data_vector,
    FUN = peptide_function,
    FUN.VALUE = numeric(4),
    amino_acids = amino_acids))

result
       C  H N  O
GHKLY 29 52 8 11
GGLY  19 34 4  9
HKLGL 26 54 8 10
```

Comment: Wow, many many thanks for this extensive answer. I have worked through your example and expanded the number of amino acids and elements to give:  data_vector <- c("CPYEEHIK", "FKDLGEQHFK", "FPNAEFAEITK", "LGEYGFQNAVLVR", "DVFLGTFLYEYSR")
result <- vapply(data_vector,
 FUN = atomComp,
 FUN.VALUE = numeric(6))

#           C  H  N  O S     D
# CPYEEHIK 45 63 11 12 1 16.95
etc...